# Unexpected token 'null' near line 1

Tags: java, api

This is query to fetch data:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<MeterSerialNumberRtc> getBlockLoadByCriteria(OnDemandRequest request) {
        List<MeterSerialNumberRtc> result =null;
        System.out.println("request"+request.getFromDate());
        System.out.println("toDate"+request.getToDate());
        System.out.println("meterserial"+request.getMeterSerials());
        try {
            final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm");
            final SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm");
            StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println("request1"+request.getFromDate());
            System.out.println("toDate1"+request.getToDate());
            System.out.println("meterserial1"+request.getMeterSerials());
            queryBuilder.append("from ActualsBlockLoad a join MeterProfile m where m.status=1");
            if (request.getFromDate() != null && request.getToDate() != null) {
                Date date = formatter.parse(request.getFromDate());
                System.out.println("Date " + date);
                String startDate = formatter1.format(date);
                Date date1 = formatter.parse(request.getToDate());
                String endDate = formatter1.format(date1);
                queryBuilder.append(" and ( a.rtc  between '" + startDate + "'  and '" + endDate + "'");
                System.out.println("queryBuider"+queryBuilder);
            }else if (request.getFromDate() != null && request.getToDate() == null) {
                Date date = formatter.parse(request.getFromDate());
                String startDate = formatter1.format(date);
                queryBuilder.append(") and a.rtc >= '" + startDate);
                System.out.println("queryBuider"+queryBuilder);
            } else if (request.getFromDate() == null && request.getToDate() != null) {
                Date date1 = formatter.parse(request.getToDate());
                String endDate = formatter1.format(date1);
                queryBuilder.append(" and a.rtc <= '" + endDate);
                System.out.println("queryBuider"+queryBuilder);
            }
            if (request.getMeterSerials().size() > 0) {
                queryBuilder.append(" and m.meterSerialNumber='" + request.getMeterSerials().get(0) + "'");
                System.out.println("queryBuider"+queryBuilder);
            }
            System.out.println("queryBuider"+queryBuilder);
            result= em.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString()).getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

but I have get error on this page like'unexpected token: null near line 1, column 223 [from com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.model.ActualsBlockLoad a join com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.model.MeterProfile m where m.status=1 and ( a.rtc  between '2020-02-28-23:00'  and '2020-02-29-23:46' and m.meterSerialNumber='IN1007137']'

This is post-call[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxQqo.png):

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line:

```
queryBuilder.append(" and ( a.rtc  between '" + startDate + "'  and '" + endDate + "'");
```

is adding an open parenthesis you don't want, and never close.

note the error has an open but no close:

`[from com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.model.ActualsBlockLoad a join com.apsilabs.meterwebapi.model.MeterProfile m where m.status=1 and ( a.rtc between '2020-02-28-23:00' and '2020-02-29-23:46' and m.meterSerialNumber='IN1007137']`

Comment: After removing the open parenthesis.It shows error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where meterprofi1_.status=1 and (actualsblo0_.rtc between '2020-02-28-23:00' and' at line 1"

Comment: You can see in that error the same open paren before `actualsblo0_.rtc` in your new error, I'm guessing your change didn't take.  I also see a close paren in the next if block which may or may not correspond to your open paren..  you should show what your `System.out.println("queryBuider"+queryBuilder);` line outputs.